# Scaling an image 2d transformation matrix

Tags: javascript, image, matrix

I wish to scale an image to a certain width (e.g. imgContainerWidth) where the aspect ratio must be maintained. I've taken the 2d transform matrix approach.

Matrix:

```
 | a  c e |
 | b  d f |
 | 0  0 1 | // This bottom row is constant.

 a = scales the element horizontally
 b = skew the the element horizontally
 c = skew the the drawing vertically
 d = scales the drawing vertically
 e = moves the the element horizontally
 f = moves the the element vertically

 matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f);

 .....


 scaleX = imgContainerWidth / imgWidth; 
 matrix[0] = scaleX; // scale X
 matrix[3] = scaleX; // scale Y

 .....
```

This scales the image nicely. However, the top of the image is not in view and needs to be moved down. I need to translate the image along y-axis. My question is how do you calculate this value so the top of the image is viewable.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out myself:

```
 scaleX = imgContainerWidth / imgWidth;
 newHeight = imgHeight * scaleX;
 translateY = newHeight - imgHeight;
```